# When using DIRECT_READ of Apache Bemas BigQueryIO, is the Streaming Buffer read?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I use Bigquery and dataflow.
When using [DIRECT_READ](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.TypedRead.html#withMethod-org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.TypedRead.Method-) of Apache Bemas BigQueryIO, is the Streaming Buffer read?

Because the number of records processed by Apache Beams does not match the number of records in the source table.

I suspect that in DIRECT_READ mode, it does not read records in the streaming buffer, but only those stored as columnar storage.

Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

DIRECT_READ reads the contents of a table directly using the BigQuery storage API. So your intuition should be correct. Here is some [information](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert) I look up about the streaming buffer.